# Double to enum cast warns types mixed

Tags: c, casting, enums, compiler-warnings

I have following C line of code where cfType is a normal C enum type:

```
int foo (double * parameters) {
...
cfType coefSelect = (cfType) *parameters; /* The double pointed by at parameters
                                           * is cast to a cfType enum and result
                                           * is put in the var coefSelect.
                                           */
...
}
```

But the compiler gives a warning at the cast line that "enumerated type mixed with another type" - but shouldn't the cast prevent this warning?

I am using Texas Instruments' C2000 C compiler in code composer studio

Comment: `enum`s are `int` types

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan they aren't, `enum` are integer types

Comment: Strange design ... S-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to cast into an integral type before to prevent this warning.

Something like:

```
cfType coefSelect = (cfType)(int) *parameters;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try casting in two steps:

```
cfType coefSelect = (cfType) (int) *parameters;
```